# How do I learn how to create a quick and easy set of draggable panes in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to enable the user to drag a bar up/down to reveal/hide content in two contiguous panes. I also need to create some buttons that move the bar to some preset locations. I know this is all possible, but am not sure where to start.

I'm creating a prototype whose purpose is to figure out the right user experience, so it's OK if it's not going to scale to 300 million simultaneous users on IE6/Windows Millenium. ;-)

Comment: Start by reading jquery UI documentation  http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/. Your need to put more effort in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a rather complicated thing to do from scratch, so consider using a plugin.  Wijmo is based on jQuery UI and has an open-source [splitter widget](http://wijmo.com/Wijmo-Open/samples/#splitter|nested).  The [documentation](http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Splitter) is decent as well.

While I don't see any methods to resize it, you may be able to add one and contribute it back to the project.

Comment: I took a look at Wijmo, and it looks like this would work. Thanks a lot!